# What is the "type signature" of pairs() in Lua?

Tags: lua

Looking at the chapter [7.1 – Iterators and Closures](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html) from "Programming in Lua" it seems like the the `for foo in bar` loop takes requires `bar` to be of type (using Java typesto express it) `Supplier<Tuple>` and the the `for-in` will keep calling `bar` until it returns `nil`.

So for something like:

```
for k,v in pairs( tables ) do
    print( 'key: '..k..', value: '..v )
end
```

that implies `pairs` has a type of `Function<Table,Supplier<Tuple>>`.

I want to create a function that behaves like `pairs` *except* it skips tuples where the first argument starts with an underscore (ie `_`).

```
local function mypairs( list )
    local --[[ Supplier<Tuple> ]] pairIterator = pairs( list )
    return --[[ Supplier<Tuple> ]] function ()
        while true do
            local key, value = pairIterator()
            if key == nil then
                return nil
            elseif key:sub(1,1) ~= '_' then
                return key, value
            end
        end
    end
end
```

however it doesn't work since

```
--[[should be: Supplier<Table>]] pairIterator = pairs({ c=3; b=2; a=1 })
```

when I call it

```
pairIterator()
```

it returns

```
stdin:1: bad argument #1 to 'pairIterator' (table expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'pairIterator'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

but

```
pairIterator({ c=3; b=2; a=1 })
```

returns

```
Lua>pairIterator({ c=3; b=2; a=1 })
c       3
```

Comment: Every function can be called with and receive zero or more arguments, each of any type. It can vary with each call. A function can use or not use each argument, with or without an expectation of its type. It can vary with each call. A function returns zero or more values, each of any type. It can vary with each call. So, "function signature" is a foreign concept. And, not to be missed, a function is a value; so, a function can be passed as an argument, an argument can be called as a function and a function can return a function. This requires a function's documentation to explain it all.

Comment: @TomBlodget while technically that is disingenous. Syntactically that is true, but it misses the point. You can call the function with anything, but there are a finite number of arrangements that produce meaningful output as expected in common usage. I read a great quote once that said something like "in every schemaless NoSql lies a poorly defined schema across the code base that accesses it". The accepting the schema <=> signature parallel, that quote holds.

Comment: I think the well-documented instances of this in the standard libraries are reasonable. My point is that one has to read the documentation for a function to see how to use it and when reading understand why things that are said are said in a certain way and that certain things wouldn't be said because they are open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pairs()` returns three separate values:

- a function to call with parameters `(table, key)` that returns a key and value
- the table you passed to it
- the first 'key' value to pass to the function (nil for pairs(), 0 for ipairs())

So something like this:

```
for k,v in pairs({a=1, b=13, c=169}) do print(k, v) end
```

Can be done like this:

```
local f,t,k = pairs({a=1, b=13, c=169})
local v
print('first k: '..tostring(k))
k,v = f(t, k)
while k ~= nil do
  print('k: '..tostring(k)..', v: '..tostring(v))
  k,v = f(t, k)
end
```

Results:

```
first k: nil
k: c, v: 169
k: b, v: 13
k: a, v: 1
```

And you don't have to take an argument, this has manual if statements for each value:

```
function mypairs()
  -- the function returned should take the table and an index, and
  -- return the next value you expect AND the next index to pass to
  -- get the value after.  return nil and nil to end
  local myfunc = function(t, val)
    if val == 0 then return 1, 'first' end
    if val == 1 then return 2, 'second' end
    if val == 2 then return 3, 'third' end
    return nil, nil
  end

  -- returns a function, the table, and the first value to pass
  -- to the function
  return myfunc, nil, 0
end

for i,v in mypairs() do
  print('i: '..tostring(i)..', v: '..tostring(v))
end

-- output:
-- i: 1, v: first
-- i: 2, v: second
-- i: 3, v: third
```

For your `mypairs(list)` you can just keep calling the function returned from pairs as long as the key has an underscore to get the next value:

```
local function mypairs( list )
  local f,t,k = pairs(list)
  return function(t,k)
    local a,b = f(t, k)
    while type(a) == 'string' and a:sub(1,1) == '_' do  a,b = f(t,a) end
    return a,b
  end, t, k
end

local list = {a=5, _b=11, c = 13, _d=69}
for k,v in mypairs(list) do print(k, v) end

-- output:
-- c    13
-- a    5
```

The docs you link to have an iterator that only returns one value and `pairs()` returns 2, but you could return more if you want.  The `for ... in ...` construct will only execute the body if the first value is non-nil.  Here's a version that also returns the keys that were skipped, the body isn't executed if you don't end up with an actual value though so you might not see all the _ keys:

```
local function mypairs( list )
  local f,t,k = pairs(list)
  return function(t,k)
    local skipped = {}
    local a,b = f(t, k)
    while type(a) == 'string' and a:sub(1,1) == '_' do
      table.insert(skipped, a)
      a,b = f(t,a)
    end
    return a,b,skipped
  end, t, k
end

local list = {a=5, _b=11, c = 13, _d=69}
for k,v,skipped in mypairs(list) do
  for i,s in ipairs(skipped) do
    print('Skipped: '..s)
  end
  print(k, v)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Your basic problem is that you're using Java logic on Lua problems. Java and Lua are different languages with different constructs, and it's important to recognize that.

`pairs` does not have a return value; it has *multiple* return values. This is a concept that Java completely lacks. A `Tuple` is a single value that can store and manipulate multiple values. A Lua function can return multiple values. This is syntactically and semantically distinct from returning a table *containing* multiple values.

The iterator-based `for` statement takes multiple values as its input, not a table or container of multiple values. Specifically, it stores 3 values: an iterator function, a state value (which you use to preserve state between calls), and an initial value.

So, if you want to mimic `pairs`'s behavior, you need to be able to store and manipulate its multiple return values.

Your first step is to store what `pairs` actually returns:

```
local f, s, var = pairs(list)
```

You are creating a new iterator function. So you need to return that, but you *also* need to return the `s` and `var` that `pairs` returns. Your return statement needs to look like this:

```
return function (s, var)
    --[[Contents discussed below]]
end, s, var --Returning what `pairs` would return.
```

Now, inside your function, you need to call `f` with `s` and `var`. This function will return the key/value pair. And you need to process them correctly:

```
return function (s, var)
    repeat
        local key, value = f(s, var)
        if(type(key) ~= "string") then
            --Non-string types can't have an `_` in them.
            --And no need to special-case `nil`.
            return key, value
        elseif(key:sub(1, 1) ~= '_') then
            return key, value
        end
    until true
end, s, var --Returning what `pairs` would return.
```

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on the difference between multiple return values and a single value containing multiple values? I assumed it was just single return with implicit destructuring.

Comment: @ArtB: I'm really not sure how to explain it any better than I just did. Multiple values are... multiple values. A value that contains multiple values is still *one value*. `return key, value` returns multiple values, as does the `return function <blah> ,s, var`part

Comment: Multiple values have to be captured with a list of the same number of variables. `iter = pairs(tbl)` captures one of three values returned by `pairs`. The other two values are required for the `for` loop to work correctly, so you must capture them with two more variables: `iter, tbl, key = pairs(tbl)`. The list of three variables is used in the `for ... in` loop: internally, `iter(tbl, key)` is called, returning `next_key, value`, and if `next_key` isn't `nil`, in the next loop `iter(tbl, next_key)` is called (and so on until the loop terminates).

Comment: I think I got, in that with _true_ multiple returns there is no way to capture all the values with a single variable. Most languages I've have used did things like packing uncaptured values into the last variable etc https://repl.it/repls/MuddyWholeControlflowgraph

Comment: @ArtB: "*there is no way to capture all the values with a single variable.*" You can; you can just stick them in a table (`{pairs(...)}`) or use `table.pack` if you want to get the length right. But it doesn't happen automatically. Multiple values are multiple values, and are treated as such.

Comment: Another perhaps useful fact: the function returned by `pairs` is identical to the global `next` function, so you could just use that instead.

Comment: This chapter ["Multiple Results"](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html) from "Programming in Lua" helps a lot.